# Show alternative image when the mouse hovers over it using bootstrap v3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I show an alternative image and hide the old image when the mouse hovers over it using bootstrap version 3 :)
Thank you very much :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this

```
<div id="sample"></div>

#sample {
   background-image: url('sampleImage1.png');
   height: 70px;
   width: 120px;
}

#sample:hover {
   background-image: url('sampleImage2.png');
}
```